# Extract text after specific word

Tags: excel, vba

I want to retrieve the text immediately after the word "for" from a string. In the example below, I want to retrieve "GLDSK8716".

> Completion Notification for GLDSK8716 -  Derivative Contracts - Futures, Forwards, Swaps, and Options

I tried this formula but it retrieves all of the text after "for".

```
=TRIM(MID(R2,SEARCH("For",R2)+LEN("for"),255))
```

Comment: have you tried any of the answers provided below ? try to give feedback and mark as "answer" to the answer you've ended up using

Answer (score 3):

This is my version with VBA:

```
Option Explicit

Public Function ExtractAfterWord(rngWord As Range, strWord As String) As String

    On Error GoTo ExtractAfterWord_Error

    Application.Volatile

    Dim lngStart        As Long
    Dim lngEnd          As Long

    lngStart = InStr(1, rngWord, strWord)
    If lngStart = 0 Then
        ExtractAfterWord = "Not Found"
        Exit Function
    End If
    lngEnd = InStr(lngStart + Len(strWord) + 1, rngWord, " ")

    If lngEnd = 0 Then lngEnd = Len(rngWord)

    ExtractAfterWord = Trim(Mid(rngWord, lngStart + Len(strWord), lngEnd - lngStart - 2))



    On Error GoTo 0
    Exit Function

ExtractAfterWord_Error:

    ExtractAfterWord = Err.Description

End Function
```

The condition in the code (`if lngEnd = 0`) is to make sure, that the formula works even if the for is before the last word in the text. A "Not Found" answer is also added.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Try `=MID(A1,FIND("for ",A1)+4,FIND(" ",A1,FIND("for ",A1)+4)-(FIND("for ",A1)+4))`

Assuming your text is in cell A1 and the pattern is `for <data> -`

Comment: I am getting error as Sub or function not defined on FIND("

Comment: Can you paste the full error. Also, is your data in cell A1?

Answer (score 0):

My solution is in VBA. The code below uses the `RegEx` to find all words between spaces. Then it loops through all words, once it finds "for" it raises a flag to indicate the next word (`RegEx.Match`) is the one you are looking for.

**Code**

```
Option Explicit

Sub ExtractNumbers()

Dim Reg1 As Object
Dim RegMatches As Variant
Dim Match As Variant
Dim NextWord As Boolean

Set Reg1 = CreateObject("VBScript.RegExp")
With Reg1
    .Global = True
    .IgnoreCase = True
    .Pattern = "\w{1,50}" ' Match any set of characters up to length of 50, untill a space
End With

Set RegMatches = Reg1.Execute(Range("R2").Value)
NextWord = False ' <-- reset flag
If RegMatches.Count >= 1 Then        
    For Each Match In RegMatches
        If NextWord Then
            MsgBox "The word you are looking for is '" & Match & "'"
            Exit Sub
        End If
        If UCase(Match) Like "FOR" Then NextWord = True '<-- "for" found >> raise flag up
    Next Match
End If

End Sub
```

Screen-shot of your string in Cell R2 and result in a `MsgBox`:

[image]